# How do I rebind M-/ in Emacs to M-- (dash)

Tags: keyboard, emacs

I'm basically trying to figure out how to use keyboard-translate in Emacs to make <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> do the same thing as <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M--") (kbd "M-/"))
```

If you use the `kbd` macro, you can use the string representation of the desired key sequence from the `C-h k` help text.